# Use ghostscript to delete a page (not extracting a range)

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I know ghostscript can use -dfirstpage -dlastpage to only make a file from a range of pages, but I need to make it (or another command line program) delete the 2nd page in any pdf where the range of pages is not explicitly told. I thought this would be far easier because most printers let you specify "1,3-end" and I have been using PDFCreator to do it that way.

The one way I can think of doing it (very very messy) is to extract page 1, extract pages 3 to end, and then merge the two pdfs. But I also don't know how to have GS determine the number of pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the right tool for the job!

For reasons outlined by KenS, Ghostscript is not the best tool for what you want to achieve. A better tool for this task is `pdftk`. To remove the 2nd page from `input.pdf`, you should run this command line:

```
pdftk  input.pdf  cat 1 3-end  output output.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

OK first things first, if you use Ghostscript's pdfwrite device you are *NOT* extracting, or deleting, or performing any other 'manipulation' operation on your source PDF file. I keep on reiterating this, but I'm going to say it again.

When you pass an input file through Ghostscript it is completely interpreted to a series of graphical primitives which are passed to the device, in general the device will render the primitives to a bitmap. In the case of the 'high level' devices such as pdfwrite, the primitives are re-assmebled into a brand new file, in the case of pdfwrite a PDF file.

This flexibility allows for input in a number of different page description languages (PostScript, PDF, PCL, PCL-XL, XPS) and then output in a few different high level formats (PostScript, EPS, flavours of PDF, XPS, PCL, PCL-XL).

But the new file bears no relation to the original, other than its appearance.

Now, having got that out of the way... You can use the pdf_info.ps PostScript program, supplied in the 'toolin' directory of the Ghostscript installation, to get a variety of information about PDF files, one of the things you can get is the number of pages in the PDF. You also don't need to bother, run the file once with -dLastPage=1, then run it again with -dFirstPage=2 (don't set LastPage), then run both resulting files to create a file with the pages from each combined.